# Add label to top annotation - complexheatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, complexheatmap

I would like to add labels (Group1, group2, group3) in the middle of each top annotation color (Group1-3). I don't know how to do this without specifying a specific cluster split (column_km = 3), since the column-order is not clustered, but manually assigned. Any idea?

```
top.ann.ffpe = HeatmapAnnotation(
  
  Group = order.ffpe$V1,
  show_legend = F,show_annotation_name = F,
  simple_anno_size = unit(0.2, "cm"),
  col = list(foo = col_fun_top.ffpe,
             Group = c("Group1" = "#c2a5cf", 
                       "Group2" = "#a6dba0", 
                       "Group3" = "#fdae61")))
```

[image]